# spring security ignores authentication-failure-url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following spring security configuration:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" entry-point-ref="httpStatusEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrentSessionFilter"/>

        <security:form-login
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-url="/api/loginFailed"
        />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"/>
        <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,sessionId"
                         success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"
        />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
```

I input wrong password and after it execution doesn't proceed in

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginFailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public String loginError(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    return getErrorMessage(httpServletRequest, SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY);
}
```

What do I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue and solution:

Based on your config:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"/>
```

All paths are secured below the `api` path. This also includes the `authenticationSuccessHandler` configuration, as per your current config:.

```
<security:form-login
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-url="/api/loginFailed"
        />
```

Spring Security is in fact redirecting back to `/api/loginFailed` on failed login attempts but since this is also a protected resource another redirect will happen to the authentication entry point. You can validate this using browser developer tools on network activity tab.

What you need to do is ensure the `authentication-failure-url` is on a **unsecured** endpoint. For example, `/loginFailed`.

So this configuration will work:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"/>

<security:form-login
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed"
        />
```

Comment: it is not issue with api

Comment: /api/loginFailed available after login